# f:$R^p$ $\rightarrow R$ such that Grf $\not=$ Cl(epigraph of f) $\cap$ Cl(subgraph of f)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For $f:\mathbb R^p$ $\rightarrow \mathbb R$ define $\mathrm{Graph}(f)=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^p\times \mathbb R\mid f(x)=y\}$.
Is there any example of a function $f:\mathbb R^p$ $\rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $\mathrm{Graph}(f)\not= \mathop{Cl}(\text{epigraph of }f) \cap \mathop{Cl}(\text{subgraph of }f)$? Here $\mathop Cl$ denotes the closure of a set.

Well, it must be a discontinuous function.
Does $x\mapsto 1/x$ for $(0,0)$ do the job?

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is the Dirichlet-function, then the closure of the epigraph is the upper halfplane, and the closure of the subgraph is $\{(x,y)\mid y\leq 1\}$.
Their intersection is the strip $\{(x,y)\mid 0\leq y\leq 1\}$, which is not the graph of $f$.